# Bash basename only gives back the last name in folder list

Tags: bash, shell

```
FOLDERS=$( basename "$(find "${LOG_DIR}" ! -path "${LOG_DIR}" -type d )")

/storage/archive/fakeagent/2018-07-12
/storage/archive/fakeagent/2018-06-22
```

With the `find` command I get this list of folders, and I would like to get the last foldername (dates). When I use `basename`, I only get back one folder name, the last one: `2018-08-16`.

How should I get all of the foldernames?

```
2018-07-12
2018-07-14
...
2018-08-16
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use option `-a` in the `basename` command to allow multiple arguments:

```
basename -a $(find "${LOG_DIR}" ! -path "${LOG_DIR}" -type d )
```

`basename --help` shows:

> -a, --multiple       support multiple arguments and treat each as a NAME

If some of your folder have spaces (or control character), you'd better use option `-exec` in the `find` command:

```
find "$LOG_DIR" -type d -exec basename "{}" \;
```

Comment: If your `basename` does support `-a`, you can also use `find ... -exec basename -a {} +` to minimize the number of times `basename` needs to be run.

Answer (score 4):

You could use awk to print whatever is after the last slash of each line:

```
find "${LOG_DIR}" ! -path "${LOG_DIR}" -type d | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
```

Or you can tell `find` to print just the basename directly:

```
find "${LOG_DIR}" ! -path "${LOG_DIR}" -type d -printf '%f\n'
```

As a side note, uppercase variable names are discouraged as they're more likely to clash with environment and shell variables, see the POSIX spec [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), fourth paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the command like this in my opinion. You are mixing folders from different locations into one list, it's largely pointless. In other words, retain the full path in your results if it is going to be of any value.  Another thing, you may want to put the values in an array so I will provide an alternative to the answers above :

```
array=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    array+=("$(echo $REPLY | sed 's:.*/::')")
done < <(find . -type d -print0)
echo ${array[@]}
```